# unclear reason why duplicate reference is needed

Tags: c#

I have a solution that includes 2 projects:

1. class library/ dll (a)
2. console application  (c)

The dll has a reference to another dll (b)

The console application project has only reference to the dll (a)

The dll (b) has a generic singleton class :

```
public class Singleton<T> where T : class
{
    private static T instance;

    public static T Instance
    {
        get
        {
            return instance;
        }
    }

    static Singleton()
    {
        instance = (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), true);
    }
}
```

The dll (a) has a class Logger that inherits from this class. In the console application program I create an instance of the logger class.

When rebuilding the project, I get this error:

> The type 'CSUtilities.Singleton`1' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'CSUtilities, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.

When I add a reference to dll(b) to the console app project the problem is solved.

**My question is**: why do I need to add a reference for dll (b) if I already have a reference for dll (a)?

Comment: Why would you think that you wouldn't have to? How would you expect DLL A to be able to work without its referenced DLL B?

Comment: @BenRobinson He's not asking that. He's asking why does he need to explicitly add the reference again when VS could do it on its own: If dll A has a reference to dll B then why doesn't VS add all dependent references of A automatically when adding dll A to the Console project. The asnwer is anyhow pretty simple: thats the way VS works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing your question is not *why* the reference to *dll B* is necessary, but *why* doesn`t *Visual Studio* add it for you automatically.

That can only be answered by the *VS* team but I can make some guesses as to why it works the way it does.

There are basically two options: automatically adding all references of *dll A* when adding *dll A* as a reference to a third project, or not adding anything but the *dll A* reference. The *VS* team chose the latter. Why?

My guess is because the requirement of referencing *dll B* is dependent on the specific code of the third project; it is not always needed so not adding it is a way to avoid unnecessarily increasing the compiled assemblies' footprint. Also, bear in mind, that if the reference is necessary, it will be made obvious at compile time with an error (your case).

On the other hand, if all references were added automatically, you would not get any error or warning indicating that `dll B` is not in use if that were the case. Yes, this could be optimized away at compile time (same as unnecessary `using` statements) but why the fuss when the other option is already pretty convenient and requires no additional work?

Answer (score 2):

> In the console application program I create an instance of the logger class.

Right - so you're creating an instance of a type which derives from `Singleton<T>`. (We'll leave aside the design issue of having a singleton you can subclass, or that apparently has a public constructor...)

Suppose you then write:

```
instance.SomeMethod();
```

How is the compiler meant to know how that can be resolved if it doesn't know about `Singleton<T>`? `Singleton<T>` is effectively part of the API of your subclass... so there has to be a reference to it.

That's at compile-time... additionally, you'd need the DLL containing `Singleton<T>` at execution time anyway. That's where you can end up with a stickier issue, if you need to add a reference to something that *isn't* needed at compile-time, because the dependency is only used in the internal implementation of the library you're actually referring to. It always feels ugly to me, but it makes perfect sense in other ways, as you definitely need the DLL to be present at execution-time.

Comment: The question is more *why* doesn't VS automatically do it for you? if *dll A* has a reference to *dll B* then, when adding a reference to *dll A* in some third project, why aren't all *dll A* references added automatically? Not doing so or doing so are arguably valid options and the VS team chose the former. My guess is that, depending on the specific code in the third assembly, maybe the reference is not necessary and the compiled assemby(s) has a smaller footprint.

Comment: @InBetween: Exactly - sometimes it's needed, sometimes it's not. But yes, it's a tricky one.

Comment: @JonSkeet, as the inBetween wrote, when I reference DLL a I expect that all its dependencies are also available. You wrote, sometimes its needed and sometimes its not. When it is needed, and why?

Comment: @mirihershkovitz Its needed whenever your code references anything defined/implemented in `dll B`. In your case `Singleton<T>`. Your way of thinking about this seems to be as if you have the misconception of *dll B* being somehow embedded in *dll A* when *dll A* is compiled. That is not the case, *dll A* and *dll B* are two independent assemblies.

Comment: @mirihershkovitz: If the way you use the DLL means that no class is ever loaded that depends on *its* dependencies, you don't need those dependencies. For example, you might have a DLL which is able to use 5 different IoC containers, but you configure your app to only use one of them... then you only need *that* IoC container.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are creating a logger in (c), the compiler needs to check this logger. the Logger is defined using the dll (b), and so the compiler must have a reference to (b) in order to compile the code callign Logger.